# Is there a way to copy guides from one Photoshop document to another?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5, guides

I'm using Photoshop CS5. I have a PSD file. We'll say it's 600x400. I have guides set up at, let's say, 100 pixels over and 27 pixels down, which I am using to position a layer correctly.

I have to do this in ten more PSDs. They are all the same 600x400. I want the guides at the same spot so when I drop in my new element, it's always at the same coordinates.

Is there a way to copy or export the guides from my original PSD to the other PSDs? I know that I *can* create a template with the guides and drag in my ten new images... I want to know if there's a quicker way.

Comment: Ugh. Sadly - no.

Comment: Create the guides and Save As abc01, abc02, abc03...

Comment: That was the last line of my question: I know I *can* do it that way, but I wanted to know if there were a *better* way.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The best way I know to "save guides" is to create an action which actually creates the guides. Some notes:

- When recording the action, it is better to create the guides using `View` → `New Guide…` rather than dragging.
- Also note that while you can type whatever unit in the guide creation box (e.g. "95%" or "2px") the action will *convert the value* to whatever the **ruler unit** is set to while recording.
- And when you later run the action, it will use the *converted* value **regardless** of what the *current* **ruler unit** is set to.

(I also [answered](https://superuser.com/questions/226711/is-it-possible-to-make-multiple-guides-at-once/226737#226737) to a [related question](https://superuser.com/q/226711/20634) on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/))

It's unfortunate that guides can't be copied in Photoshop in the same manner as they can be in other programs like InDesign.

Answer (score 9):

I recently came across http://www.guideguide.me/ as well, and it is a wonderful tool to save presets like these without having to modify any configuration file. It's very solid and intuitive.

Answer (score 6):

Someone dear to me made this script because I needed to copy and paste guides from one doc. to another. This script will let you import and export preexisting guides in your documents. The instructions on how to use it are included. http://www.mediafire.com/?zz7j7t3fl824p31

Answer (score 3):

You can also modify the "default new doc sizes.txt" and create your own "guide templates". You have to be careful to copy the original so you can revert it back if need be. A bit of math is needed to break down the percentages but once complete it works like a dream.

Here is my example:

"web"

```
"640 x 480"                     640     480    pixels  screen dpi RGB 8 1.0
"800 x 600"                  800     600    pixels  screen dpi RGB 8 1.0
"1024 x 768"                1024     768    pixels  screen dpi RGB 8 1.0
"1152 x 864"                1152     864    pixels  screen dpi RGB 8 1.0
"1280 x 1024"               1280    1024    pixels  screen dpi RGB 8 1.0
"1280 x 1024 (2 column equal)"      1280    1024    pixels  screen dpi RGB 8 1.0    white "none" 11.72 v 12.5 v 49.61 v 50.0 v 50.39 v 87.5 v 88.28 v
"1280 x 1024 (2 column left)"       1280    1024    pixels  screen dpi RGB 8 1.0    white "none" 11.72 v 12.5 v 35.16 v 35.94 v 87.5 v 88.28 v
"1280 x 1024 (2 column right)"      1280    1024    pixels  screen dpi RGB 8 1.0    white "none" 11.72 v 12.5 v 64.06 v 64.84 v 87.5 v 88.28 v
"1280 x 1024 (3 column equal)"      1280    1024    pixels  screen dpi RGB 8 1.0    white "none" 11.72 v 12.5 v 36.72 v 37.89 v 62.11 v 63.28 v 87.5 v 88.28 v
"1600 x 1200"               1600    1200    pixels  screen dpi RGB 8 1.0
```

Comment: can you explain your example a bit more? I'm seeing a string of data which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Lauren: He's talking about modifying a configuration file for Photoshop that specifies the various presets you're presented with when you create a new document. Perhaps tbbjr can include the default location of this file in his answer to make this more clear.

Answer (score 3):

I generally just turn smart guides on and use shapes/paths (boxes and lines primarily). It's easy to wireframe using simple shapes and then use them for guides as well.

At some point I'll usually deleted the shapes and actually replace them with real guides. But that's usually later in the design process when the wireframe is locked in.

Answer (score 2):

[GuideGuide](http://www.cameronmcefee.com/guideguide/) is an excellent tool to create guides just by inputting values. This could be very useful, especially if you're a web designer as you can create a complete grid with margins, columns and gutters.

Answer (score 2):

I've used JavaScript to batch redefine guides on multiple documents at once in the past, but I can't for the life of me find the link to the actual script. [This isn't the script I used](http://www.vcarrer.com/2011/11/make-photoshop-guides-grid-with.html), but it seems to do the same thing (though I'm not sure if in simultaneous multiples) so you might find it useful.

GuideGuide sounds like a much easier way of doing this for individual documents, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy guides in Photoshop. Now I will tell you how.

### Install scripts

- Download the following two files:

  - [Guides Copy.jsx](https://www.reflections-ibs.com/media/1241/guides-copy.jsx)
  - [Guides Paste.jsx](https://www.reflections-ibs.com/media/1242/guides-paste.jsx)
- Open Adobe Photoshop installation folder and go to the "Presets" folder and then to the "Scripts" folder. (For me it's `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop 2020\Presets\Scripts`.)
- Copy the two scripts to this location.

### Usage

- Run Photoshop
- Open the two documents (the one you will copy the guides from and the one you need to paste the guides to).
- Select the first document and click from menu: *File > Scripts > Guides Copy*.
- Then select the second document and click from menu: *File > Scripts > Guides Paste*.

That will copy the guides from the first document to the second one.

### Further details

Article: [How To Copy Guides From One Photoshop Document To Another](https://www.reflections-ibs.com/blog/articles/how-to-copy-guides-from-one-photoshop-document-to-another)

Video: [How To Copy Guides From One Photoshop Document To Another](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ua9R6ggF5bY)

*I'm CEO & Founder at Reflections who made these scripts available.*

Comment: Hi there Omar and welcome to the site.  I've taken the liberty of editing your answer to add some formatting and correct a few language issues. I hope you are OK with these corrections. If not you can rollback to the previous version and/or edit yourself. I can see from your profile that you work for the company that provides these scripts. That is fine, but please edit and add a line explaining your affiliation.

Comment: Thanks @Wolff, no problem at all.

Comment: @Wolff what kind of explaining you need ?
I already stated that i'm the founder of Reflections in my profile

Comment: See [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). Your affiliation must  be disclosed in the answer itself. Just add something like this at the end: *(I'm CEO & Founder at Reflections who made these scripts available.)* or similar.

Comment: Hi Omar, thanks for contributing! Please read [our guidelines](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) about self-promotion. It's good that you've already disclosed your affiliation on your profile, but it wouldn't hurt to do that in the answer too. Also, if you only post answers linking back to your site, that's kind of spammy. So keep contributing and enjoying the site and you'll become a valued member in no time.

Comment: Thanks @Wolff for your clarification, I will edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks @PieBie for your clarification, I will edit the answer,
and about spamming don't worry I already answer question without any links - 1 out of 2 :)